# Problem in using CustomControls in a ItemsControl's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, winui-3

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469448/bind-datatemplate-to-customcontrol-problem) before starting to ask this one. I wasn't able to get enough information from that question because I wasn't able to match it to my problem and most of the referenced links were broken so I wasn't able to access to them.

Here is my problem:

I have designed a `CustomControl` in `WinUI3` which has some glue-like properties in the `code-behind`:

```
public sealed class StimulationListItem : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StimulationTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StimulationType), typeof(StimulationType), typeof(StimulationListItem), new PropertyMetadata(StimulationType.Irrelevant));

    public StimulationType StimulationType
    {
        get => (StimulationType)GetValue(StimulationTypeProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(StimulationTypeProperty, value);
            switch (value)
            {
                case StimulationType.Type1:
                    BadgeVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    break;
                case StimulationType.Type2:
                    BadgeVisibility= Visibility.Visible;
                    BadgeText = "Type2";
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Same for StimNumber, BadgeText, StimVisibility, BadgeVisibility, ...
    }
}
```

I have defined a `ControlTemplate` which works fine with this `CustomControl`:

```
<Style TargetType="local:StimulationListItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="72"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:StimulationListItem">
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                      <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding StimNumber}"/>
                      <local:Badge Text="{TemplateBinding BadgeText}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding BadgeVisibility}">
                      </local:Badge>
                      <!-- Rest of control template design -->
                 </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tested the logic behind this `CustomControl` alone, It works fine.
So I tried to use it in a LisView as a base element type:

```
 <Page>
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.Stimulations}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:StimulationViewModel">
                 <local:StimulationListItem StimulationType="{Binding StimulationType}"
                                       <!-- Rest of binding stuffs -->
                                       Margin="0 0 0 12"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
 </Page>
```

In the `Page` code-behind I have `myViewModel`

```
    public MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; private set; }
```

and it defined as:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<StimulationViewModel> Stimulations { get; }
    public MyViewModel() { /* Collection is filled here */ }
}
```

I have defined a `StimulationViewModel` which has nearly same property set of the `CustomControl` including (`StimulationType`, `StimNumber` and `BadgeText` , ...).

```
 public class StimulationViewModel {
    public string StimNumber { get; set; }
    public StimulationType StimulationType { get; set; }
 }
```

I've just removed extra controlling fields to make it more meaningful.
The problem is that: my `CustomControl` elements are getting filled with `StimulationViewModel`, but none of `StimulationListItem` properties (setters) are getting called so none of my glue-like logic which are defined in the `CustomControl` is not working at all.

I think `StimulationViewModel` has overridden my main `CustomControl`s properties. because I tried to Replace `StimulationViewModel` with my `CustomControl` (StimulationListItem) in my `ObservableCollection` in `ListView` binding-stuffs, and it worked as I expected.

Should I design `ControlTemplates` for `ViewModels` or the `Code-Behinds` of my `CustomControls` are the same `ViewModels` that I'm looking for. I have missed something I can't understand.

Why this two level binding:

- `TemplateBinding` which binds `ControlTemplate` elements to `CustomControl` properties.
- `Binding` which binds `CustomControls` dependecy properties to `StimulationViewModel`
  is not working as a chain? Am I thinking wrong ?

tnx for any help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the reason why your code doesn't work as expected.

In this case, generally speaking, you create `StimulationViewModel`s, not `StimulationListItem`s as items source,

```cs
//public ObservableCollection<StimulationListItem> Stimulations { get; }
public ObservableCollection<StimulationViewModel> Stimulations { get; }
```

then pass those view models to the `ItemsSource`, and define your view items in the `ItemTemplate`:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Stimulations}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:StimulationViewModel">
            <local:StimulationListItem
                StimNumber="{x:Bind StimNumber, Mode=OneWay}"
                StimulationType="{x:Bind StimulationType, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This way, you can also avoid having UI parts, `StimulationListItem` in this case, in your view model.

Comment: One additional tip. Since you can define the `DataType` in the `ItemTemplate`, you should use `x:Bind` over `Binding` whenever you can. `x:Bind` is more efficient and error-prone (compile-time check).

Comment: Thank you @Andrew . It worked , So you think technically it's a bug ? and I'm not wrong ? actually I'm not pro at `MVVM` and this is my first project.

Comment: If the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640753/problem-in-using-customcontrols-in-a-itemscontrols-datatemplate/76640921?noredirect=1#comment135125691_76640921:~:text=//public%20ObservableCollection%3CStimulationListItem%3E%20Stimulations%20%7B%20get%3B%20%7D%0Apublic%20ObservableCollection%3CStimulationViewModel%3E%20Stimulations%20%7B%20get%3B%20%7D) in my answer fixed your problem, I don't think this is a WinUI 3 bug. You should try to avoid creating UI objects on view models.